# php honeypot field needs to redirect to certain page if value is present or other page is null

Tags: php, forms

I have a 2-page form to gather potential client data, and using a honeypot field to stop spam from entering our database table.
The code inserts the data into the table, so that is not an issue.

What I want to have happen is if the honeypot field is NOT NULL, then I want it to redirect to the **noway.html** file.  Otherwise, redirect to the **home.html** file.

index.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once 'config/config.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Purchase Form | HomePromise</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container box">
   <h2 class="page-title" align="center">Purchase Form</h2><br />
    <form method="post" id="refi_form" action="index2.php">
    <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:16px;">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="fins_details">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Refi label: <label>What's the value of your home?</label> -->
            <input type="hidden" name="branch" id="branch" class="form-control" value="Army" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
            <label>What is the sales price of your home?</label>
            <select name="salesprice" id="salesprice" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="75000">50,000 - 99,999</option>
                <option value="150000">100,000 - 199,999</option>
                <option value="250000">200,000 - 299,999</option>
                <option value="350000">300,000 - 399,999</option>
                <option value="450000">400,000 - 499,999</option>
                <option value="550000">500,000 - 599,999</option>
                <option value="650000">600,000 - 699,999</option>
                <option value="700000">Over 700,000</option>
            <span id="error_salesprice" class="text-danger"></span>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>What loan amount do you want?</label>
            <select name="loan_amount" id="loan_amount" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="75000">50,000 - 99,999</option>
                <option value="150000">100,000 - 199,999</option>
                <option value="250000">200,000 - 299,999</option>
                <option value="350000">300,000 - 399,999</option>
                <option value="450000">400,000 - 499,999</option>
                <option value="550000">500,000 - 599,999</option>
                <option value="650000">600,000 - 699,999</option>
                <option value="700000">Over 700,000</option>
            <span id="error_loan_amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>What is your yearly income?</label>
            <select name="income" id="income" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="25000">Under 25k</option>
                <option value="37000">25k - 49k</option>
                <option value="62000">50k - 74k</option>
                <option value="87000">75k - 99k</option>
                <option value="125000">100k - 149k</option>
                <option value="175000">150k - 200k</option>
                <option value="200000">Over 200k</option>
            <span id="error_income" class="text-danger"></span>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div align="right">
      <input type='submit' name='save' id='btn_fins_details' style="background-color:rgb(50,50,200);color:#fff;font-size:1.5em;padding:10px;" value="Next">
</div>
    </div>
     </div>
      </div>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<script src="../assets/js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

index2.php (Note: I am only echoing the values to verify that the honeypot and other values are being stored in their sessions.):

```
    <?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['branch'] = $_POST['branch'];
$_SESSION['salesprice'] = $_POST['salesprice'];
$_SESSION['loan_amount'] = $_POST['loan_amount'];
$_SESSION['income'] = $_POST['income'];
$_SESSION['formurl'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo $_SESSION['branch']; ?><br><?php
echo $_SESSION['salesprice']; ?><br><?php
echo $_SESSION['loan_amount']; ?><br><?php
echo $_SESSION['income']; ?><br><?php
echo $_SESSION['formurl']; ?><br><?php
$client_url = $_POST['client_url'];
require_once 'config/config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Refinance Form | HomePromise</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container box">
   <br />
   <h2 class="page-title" align="center">Purchase Form</h2><br />
    <form method="post" id="refi_form" action="submit.php">
    <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:16px;">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="fins_details">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-body">
       <table class="center">
        <tr>
           <td class="left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="formurl" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['formurl']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="client_url" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['client_url']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ip']; ?>"></input>

                <input type="hidden" name="branch" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['branch']; ?>"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="salesprice" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['salesprice']; ?>"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="loan_amount" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['loan_amount']; ?>"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="income" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['income']; ?>"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="transaction_type" id="transaction_type" value="Purchase">
                    
                    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" class="form-control" />
                    <span id="error_fName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            
                </tr>
</table>
<br />
        <div class="text-message" style="display: block;">
        <p>By clicking submit below, I/we acknowledge that I/we have read and agree to the <a href="https://homepromise.com/user/">User Agreement</a> and acknowledge that I/we have read the <a href="https://homepromise.com/privacy/">Privacy</a> Statement, and <a href="https://homepromise.com/disclosures/">Disclosures</a>.</p>
        <br />
        </div>
        <div align="right">
      <input type='submit' name='save' id='btn_personal_details' style="background-color:rgb(50,50,200);color:#fff;font-size:1.5em;padding:10px;" value="Submit">
    </div>
     </div>
      </div>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
 <script src="..assets/js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

submit.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['branch'] = $_POST['branch'];

require_once 'config/config.php';
if (isset($_POST['client_url']) && $_POST['formurl'] && $_POST['ip'] && $_POST['salesprice'] && $_POST['loan_amount'] && $_POST['transaction_type'] && $_POST['fName'] && (empty($_POST['branch']))) {
$client_url = $_POST['client_url'];
$formurl = $_POST['formurl'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
$salesprice = $_POST['salesprice'];
$loan_amount = $_POST['loan_amount'];
$income = $_POST['income'];
$transaction_type = $_POST['transaction_type'];
$fName = $_POST['fName'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO whp (client_url, formurl, ip, salesprice, loan_amount, income, transaction_type, fName) VALUES ('$client_url', '$formurl', '$ip', '$salesprice', '$loan_amount', '$income', '$transaction_type', '$fName')";
  $db_con->exec($sql);
  header("Location: home.html");
} else {
  header("Location: noway.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you use csrf tokens, to prevent this issue from happening

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen FYI, csrf tokens have absolutely nothing to do with this issue

Comment: due to SQL injection all the clients data is freely available to any person willing to take it. This code is a shame to the profession

Comment: to solve your sql injection issue, use MSQL_PDO

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen FYI,  there is no such thing as "MSQL_PDO" and the op is already using PDO

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm surprised PHP still has that option available. OP should be using PDO to bind parameters. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo
This has been standard for over a decade. I don't know why you've downvoted my answer though. The answer is correct for what the OP wanted.

Comment: I am using PDO in my connection file:<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
  $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

Comment: @wilcan you need to use the prepare function for your statement and then bind your parameters to placeholders. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @Zei, thanks for that info.  I bound the parameters after reading the link you provided.

Comment: @wilcan good work. Make sure you exclusively use the prepare/bind pattern when making database queries. It seems like a lot of extra work, but it is actually escaping all of the input parameters. If you didn't do it this way, people could execute whatever database query they want through your website. By the way, this goes for all programming languages. All languages have an equivalent of this pattern.

Comment: @Zei, I was finally able to get all of the code working, thanks to your advice on the prepared statements and binding the parameters.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Create your honeypot input (name can be whatever, in my example I'm using `honeypot`).

```php
if (empty($_POST['honeypot'])){
```

Add that just after the $sql string is set (or just before).

`empty` will return true if the variable is undefined or set to false. In terms of a POST value, that means it will be true if the POST value is not set or is blank (and you should trigger home.html). If it's filled, it it will return false and you should trigger the `else` noway.html.